# SortCompareFunction with always same result creates EAccessViolation

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, sortcomparefunction

What is the exact reason for the `SortCompareObjects` function getting an `EAccessViolation` if it always returns the same result (as opposed to a changing result e.g. with `CompareText`)?

```
function SortCompareObjects(Item1, Item2: Pointer): Integer;
begin
  Result := 1; // EAccessViolation
  // Result := CompareText(...); // No EAccessViolation
end;

MyObjectList: System.Contnrs.TObjectList;

MyObjectList := System.Contnrs.TObjectList.Create;

for i := 0 to x do
  MyObjectList.Add(AObject);

MyObjectList.Sort(@SortCompareObjects); // EAccesViolation
```

Comment: It would work for Result := 0. This would mean all elements are the same. Have the same "size". But are basically saying every element is bigger from all the rest. See the paradox :)

Comment: Under the assumption that the sort algorithm is sequential: If `Result := 1;`, wouldn't ElementA just get shifted upwards in the first algorithmic step, and then in the next sequential step ElementB also just get shifted upwards?

Comment: The sort algorithm used in Delphi is QuickSort. So it is not sequential but recursive with divide and conquer approach. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A comparison sort algorithm accesses elements in an array under the assumption that the sort function has certain properties. Specifically,

- If f(x,y)<0 then f(y,x)>0
- If f(x,y)=0 then f(y,x)=0
- If f(x,y)<0 and f(y,z)<0 then f(x,z)<0
- f(x,x)=0

The sort algorithm guarantees that it will sort the array if your function obeys the rules. Otherwise, if you don't obey the rules, all bets are off. Anything could happen. Don't be surprised if you encounter runtime errors. The most commonly seen, in my experience, is stack overflow, but access violation is plausible too.

Answer (score 1):

> Under the assumption that the sort algorithm is sequential ...

That's a very wrong assumption, one you don't need to make. First of all, unless you're on a trial version of Delphi, you can see the source code; It's QucikSort, not anything else. The second problem is, what's a "sequential" sort algorithm? I've never heard of one!

To answer your question directly, here's a snip of code from the `QuickSort` algorithm used by Delphi. `SCompare` is the function you supplied, the one that *always* reutrns `1`

```
  while SCompare(SortList^[J], P) > 0 do
    Dec(J);
```

Since `1` is *always* grater then zero, that loop would never stop. It only stops when `SortList^[j]` generates an access violation, and that's bound to happen sooner or later.

Comment: He probably meant the easiest sort that is teached as an example of O(n*n). Its called selection sort. You basically start at element 0 then scan the whole array of elements picking the smallest, the you start at element 1 etc... If that was the case, his assumption would actually be correct (He would always pick the last element of the array, wrong sure, but it would not AV or anything). But its QuickSort as you said, so it fails.